# Calculating price change when changing select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm sure this as been ask before but I am unable to find an answer.

What i'm trying to do:

- Update a price field `<p class="price">&pound;<span>50.00</span></p>` when a user changes a select box
- Have multiple select boxes that work together on updating the price correctly
- reset the price if all select boxes are at original values

**NOTE:** I am not very flexible with changing the HTML layout.

Heres what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<p class="price">&pound;<span>50.00</span></p>

<select name="s1">
    <option value="1" data-price="0">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="10.10">Item 2 + &pound;10.10</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="20.10">Item 3 + &pound;20.10</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="30.10">Item 4 + &pound;30.10</option>
</select>

<select name="s2">
    <option value="1" data-price="0">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="10.10">Item 2 + &pound;10.10</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="20.10">Item 3 + &pound;20.10</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="30.10">Item 4 + &pound;30.10</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
var price = $('.price span').text();
$('.price').attr({'data-current': price, 'data-price': price})

$('select').change(function(){
    var $price = $('.price span');
    //var originPrice = parseFloat($('.price').attr('data-price'));
    var currentPrice = parseFloat($('.price').attr('data-current'));
    var addPrice = parseFloat($(this).children('option[value='+$(this).val()+']').attr('data-price'));
    var newPrice = '';

    if(isNaN(addPrice) || addPrice == 0){
        //reset
        var reset = $('.price').attr('data-price');
        $price.text(reset)
        $('.price').attr('data-current', reset)
    } 
    else {
        newPrice = currentPrice + addPrice;
        $price.text(parseFloat(newPrice).toFixed(2))
        $('.price').attr('data-current', newPrice)
    }

});
```

Its looking quite messy at the moment, I have created this as a test from the default Eshop (Wordpress) product page layout. Eshop displays the price and select boxes similar to:

```
<option value="2" data-price="10.10">Item 2 + &pound;10.10</option>
```

I have added all `data` values, currently my example is not full working as select boxes override each other and i'm not sure how to fix it. And ideas?

[**Here is the JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8D3tJ/)

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/8D3tJ/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, you want to add the values selected in the `select` elements to the initial price. If that's the case you can massively simplify your code. Try this:

```
$('.price-option').change(function(){
    var price = parseFloat($('.price').data('base-price'));

    $('.price-option').each(function(i, el) {
        price += parseFloat($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
    });

    $('.price span').text(price.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8D3tJ/2/)

Comment: That's spot on thanks! I was completely over complicating it just as I thought.